# Lazy module variables--can it be done?

Tags: python, module, variables, lazy-loading, itunes

I'm trying to find a way to lazily load a module-level variable.

Specifically, I've written a tiny Python library to talk to iTunes, and I want to have a `DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH` module variable. Unfortunately, iTunes won't tell you where its download folder is, so I've written a function that grabs the filepath of a few podcast tracks and climbs back up the directory tree until it finds the "Downloads" directory.

This takes a second or two, so I'd like to have it evaluated lazily, rather than at module import time.

Is there any way to lazily assign a module variable when it's first accessed or will I have to rely on a function?

Comment: **Note to future readers:** Since Python 3.7 (8 years after this was asked) [this is now possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54616590/736937) with module level `__getattr__`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can't do it with modules, but you can disguise a class "as if" it was a module, e.g., in `itun.py`, code...:

```
import sys

class _Sneaky(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.download = None

  @property
  def DOWNLOAD_PATH(self):
    if not self.download:
      self.download = heavyComputations()
    return self.download

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return globals()[name]

# other parts of itun that you WANT to code in
# module-ish ways

sys.modules[__name__] = _Sneaky()
```

Now anybody can `import itun`... and get in fact your `itun._Sneaky()` instance. The `__getattr__` is there to let you access anything else in `itun.py` that may be more convenient for you to code as a top-level module object, than inside `_Sneaky`!_)

Answer (score 19):

It turns out that as of Python 3.7, it's possible to do this cleanly by defining a `__getattr__()` at the module level, as specified in [PEP 562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/) and documented in the [data model chapter](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-module-attribute-access) in the Python reference documentation.

```
# mymodule.py

from typing import Any

DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH: str

def _download_folder_path() -> str:
    global DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH
    DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH = ... # compute however ...
    return DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH

def __getattr__(name: str) -> Any:
    if name == "DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH":
        return _download_folder_path()
    raise AttributeError(f"module {__name__!r} has no attribute {name!r}")
```

Comment: This throws `NameError: name 'DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH' is not defined`

Answer (score 13):

I used Alex' implementation on Python 3.3, but this crashes miserably:
The code

```
  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return globals()[name]
```

is not correct because an `AttributeError` should be raised, not a `KeyError`.
This crashed immediately under Python 3.3, because a lot of introspection is done
during the import, looking for attributes like `__path__`, `__loader__` etc.

Here is  the version that we use now in our project to allow for lazy imports
in a module. The `__init__` of the module is delayed until the first attribute access
that has not a special name:

```
""" config.py """
# lazy initialization of this module to avoid circular import.
# the trick is to replace this module by an instance!
# modelled after a post from Alex Martelli :-)
```

[Lazy module variables--can it be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462986/lazy-module-variables-can-it-be-done)

```
class _Sneaky(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.module = sys.modules[name]
        sys.modules[name] = self
        self.initializing = True

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # call module.__init__ after import introspection is done
        if self.initializing and not name[:2] == '__' == name[-2:]:
            self.initializing = False
            __init__(self.module)
        return getattr(self.module, name)

_Sneaky(__name__)
```

The module now needs to define an **init** function. This function can be used
to import modules that might import ourselves:

```
def __init__(module):
    ...
    # do something that imports config.py again
    ...
```

The code can be put into another module, and it can be extended with properties
as in the examples above.

Maybe that is useful for somebody.

Answer (score 10):

For Python 3.5 and 3.6, the *proper* way of doing this, [according to the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-module-attribute-access), is to subclass `types.ModuleType` and then dynamically update the module's `__class__`. So, here's a solution loosely on [Christian Tismer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14345798/5223757) but probably not resembling it much at all:

```
import sys
import types

class _Sneaky(types.ModuleType):
    @property
    def DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_download_folder_path'):
            self._download_folder_path = '/dev/block/'
        return self._download_folder_path
sys.modules[__name__].__class__ = _Sneaky
```

For Python 3.7 and later, you can define a module-level `__getattr__()` function.  See [PEP 562](https://peps.python.org/pep-0562/) for details.

Comment: This doesn't work on Py2.7: `__class__ assignment: only for heap types`

Comment: @AshBerlin-Taylor You're _still using Python 2.7‽_ It hits EOL at the start of 2020; [you've got just over 9 months to migrate _away_ from it before it comes insecure!](https://pythonclock.org/) You especially shouldn't be writing new software in it. It'd be [downright irresponsible for me to provide you a way of doing this, which I most certainly will not do in any shape or form. Please disregard the blueness of this text, which I **do not endorse in any shape or form**.](https://github.com/wizzwizz4/strictpy/blob/master/strict/utils.py#L26-L50)

Comment: I wish I wasn't, but we've still got to support Py.27 it for now.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the python docs talking about this?

Comment: @Spidey Talking about which part?

Comment: You mentioned the answer is based on python documentation: `The proper way of doing this, according to the Python docs`

Comment: @Spidey I can't remember, sorry. I assume I read something about `sys.modules` being supposed to contain modules, and about changing `__class__` to make sure nothing still referenced the old version, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Spidey Here is a [link](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-module-attribute-access) to the docs you asked for. "For a more fine grained customization of the module behavior (setting attributes, properties, etc.), one can set the `__class__` attribute of a module object to a subclass of types.ModuleType."  It also gives a helpful example.

Comment: This approach triggers a weakness in doctests, which only access statically-defined properties on the module. https://bugs.python.org/issue46619

Comment: @RichardHansen Thanks for fixing up my answer!

Answer (score 7):

Since Python 3.7 (and as a result of [PEP-562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/)), this is now possible with the module-level `__getattr__`:

Inside your module, put something like:

```
def _long_function():
    # print() function to show this is called only once
    print("Determining DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH...")
    # Determine the module-level variable
    path = "/some/path/here"
    # Set the global (module scope)
    globals()['DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH'] = path
    # ... and return it
    return path


def __getattr__(name):
    if name == "DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH":
        return _long_function()

    # Implicit else
    raise AttributeError(f"module {__name__!r} has no attribute {name!r}")
```

From this it should be clear that the `_long_function()` isn't executed when you import your module, e.g.:

```
print("-- before import --")
import somemodule
print("-- after import --")
```

results in just:

```
-- before import --
-- after import --
```

But when you attempt to access the name *from* the module, the module-level `__getattr__` will be called, which in turn will call `_long_function`, which will perform the long-running task, cache it as a module-level variable, and return the result back to the code that called it.

For example, with the first block above inside the module "somemodule.py", the following code:

```
import somemodule
print("--")
print(somemodule.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH)
print('--')
print(somemodule.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH)
print('--')
```

produces:

```
--
Determining DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH...
/some/path/here
--
/some/path/here
--
```

or, more clearly:

```
# LINE OF CODE                                # OUTPUT
import somemodule                             # (nothing)

print("--")                                   # --

print(somemodule.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH)        # Determining DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH...
                                              # /some/path/here

print("--")                                   # --

print(somemodule.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH)        # /some/path/here

print("--")                                   # --
```

Lastly, you can also implement `__dir__` as the PEP describes if you want to indicate (e.g. to code introspection tools) that `DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_PATH` *is* available.

Answer (score 4):

*Is there any way to lazily assign a module variable when it's first accessed or will I have to rely on a function?*

I think you are correct in saying that a function is the best solution to your problem here. 
I will give you a brief example to illustrate.

```
#myfile.py - an example module with some expensive module level code.

import os
# expensive operation to crawl up in directory structure
```

The expensive operation will be executed on import if it is at module level. There is not a way to stop this, short of lazily importing the entire module!!

```
#myfile2.py - a module with expensive code placed inside a function.

import os

def getdownloadsfolder(curdir=None):
    """a function that will search upward from the user's current directory
        to find the 'Downloads' folder."""
    # expensive operation now here.
```

You will be following best practice by using this method.

Comment: Hmmmm. It's the obvious and simplest way to do it, so in line with the Zen of Python, but I just don't like it API-wise.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I came across the same problem, and have found a way to do it.

```
class LazyObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.initialized = False
        setattr(self, 'data', None)

    def init(self, *args):
        #print 'initializing'
        pass

    def __len__(self): return len(self.data)
    def __repr__(self): return repr(self.data)

    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        if object.__getattribute__(self, 'initialized') == False:
            object.__getattribute__(self, 'init')(self)
            setattr(self, 'initialized', True)

        if key == 'data':
            return object.__getattribute__(self, 'data')
        else:
            try:
                return object.__getattribute__(self, 'data').__getattribute__(key)
            except AttributeError:
                return super(LazyObject, self).__getattribute__(key)
```

With this `LazyObject`, You can define a `init` method for the object, and the object will be initialized lazily, example code looks like:

```
o = LazyObject()
def slow_init(self):
    time.sleep(1) # simulate slow initialization
    self.data = 'done'
o.init = slow_init
```

the `o` object above will have exactly the same methods whatever `'done'` object have, for example, you can do:

```
# o will be initialized, then apply the `len` method 
assert len(o) == 4
```

complete code with tests (works in 2.7) can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/observerss/007fedc5b74c74f3ea08

Answer (score 1):

If that variable lived in a class rather than a module, then you could overload getattr, or better yet, populate it in init.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I wanted it in a module for the sake of the API.

In a class, I'd use `property` to do it, though. Great for lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

#### SPEC 1

Probably the best known recipe for Lazy Loading module attributes (and modules) is in **[SPEC 1](https://scientific-python.org/specs/spec-0001/)** *(Draft)* at scientific-python.org. [SPECs](https://scientific-python.org/specs/) are operational guidelines for projects in the Scientific Python ecosystem. There is discussion around the SPEC 1 at [Scientific Python Discourse](https://discuss.scientific-python.org/t/spec-1-lazy-loading-for-submodules/25) and the solution is offered as a package in PyPI as **[lazy_loader](https://github.com/scientific-python/lazy_loader)**. The lazy_loader implementation relies on the module `__gettattr__` support introduced in Python 3.7 ([PEP 562](https://peps.python.org/pep-0562/)), and it is used in [scikit-image](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/5101), [NetworkX](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/4909), and [partially in Scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/15230)

##### Example usage:

The following example is using the [lazy_loader](https://pypi.org/project/lazy_loader/) PyPI package. You could also just copy-paste the [source code](https://github.com/scientific-python/lazy_loader/blob/main/lazy_loader/__init__.py) to be part of your project.

```py
# mypackage/__init__.py
import lazy_loader

__getattr__, __dir__, __all__ = lazy_loader.attach(
    __name__,
    submodules=['bar'],
    submod_attrs={
        'foo.morefoo': ['FooFilter', 'do_foo', 'MODULE_VARIABLE'],
        'grok.spam': ['spam_a', 'spam_b', 'spam_c']
    }
)
```

this is the lazy import equivalent of

```py
from . import bar
from .foo.morefoo import FooFilter, do_foo, MODULE_VARIABLE
from .grok.spam import (spam_a, spam_b, spam_c)
```

##### Short explanation on lazy_loader.attach

- If you want to lazy-load a *module*, you list it in `submodules` (which is a list)
- If you want to lazy-load something *from a module* (function, class, etc.), you list it in `submod_attrs` (which is a dict)

#### Type checking

Static type checkers and IDEs cannot infer type information from lazily loaded imports. As workaround, you may use [type stubs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html) (.pyi files), like this:

```
# mypackage/__init__.pyi
from .foo.morefoo import FooFilter as FooFilter, do_foo as do_foo, MODULE_VARIABLE as MODULE_VARIABLE
from .grok.spam import spam_a as spam_a, spam_b as spam_b, spam_c as spam_c
```

The [SPEC 1](https://scientific-python.org/specs/spec-0001/#type-checkers) mentions that this `X as X` syntax is [necessary due to PEP484](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/3989#issuecomment-1260194688).

#### Side notes

- There was recently a PEP for Lazy Imports, [PEP 690](https://pep-previews.readthedocs.io/pep-0690/), but it was rejected.
- In [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow), there is lazy loading class at [util.lazyloader](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py).
- There is one [blog post](https://snarky.ca/lazy-importing-in-python-3-7/) from Brett Cannon (a Python core developer), where he showed in 2018 a module `__getattr__` based implementation of lazy_loader, and provided it in a package called [modutil](https://github.com/brettcannon/modutil), but the project is marked archived in GitHub. This has been [an inspiration](https://scientific-python.org/specs/spec-0001/) for the scientific-python lazy_loader.