# Sphinx document module properties

Tags: python, properties, python-sphinx, metaclass, python-module

I have a module that should have a `@property`, I solved this by setting a class as the module. I got the idea from this answer: [Lazy module variables--can it be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462986/lazy-module-variables-can-it-be-done/1463773#1463773)

I wanted this to be repeatable and easy to use so I made a metaclass for it. This works like a charm.

The problem is that when using Sphinx to generate documentation properties don't get documented. Everything else is documented as expected. I have no idea how to fix this, maybe this is a problem with Sphinx?

The module:

```
import sys
import types

class ClassAsModule(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        # Make sure the name of the class is the module name.
        name = attrs.pop('__module__')
        # Create a class.
        cls = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        # Instantiate the class and register it.
        sys.modules[name] = cls = cls(name)
        # Update the dict so dir works properly
        cls.__dict__.update(attrs)

class TestClass(types.ModuleType):
    """TestClass docstring."""
    __metaclass__ = ClassAsModule
    @property
    def some_property(self):
        """Property docstring."""
        pass
    def meth():
        """meth doc"""
        pass
```

And a copy-paste to generate/view Sphinx documentation:

```
sphinx-apidoc . -o doc --full
sphinx-build doc html
xdg-open html/module.html
```

The most essential part is to document the class' properties. Bonus points to also document original module members.

**EDIT:** The class should be documented as the module it is in. The class is used this way and should thus appear this way in Sphinx.

Example of desired output:

```
Module Foo
    TestClass docstring.

    some_property
        Property docstring.

    meth()
        meth doc
```

**EDIT 2:** I found something that may aid in finding a solution. When having a regular module `foo` with the following content:

```
#: Property of foo
prop = 'test'
```

Sphinx documents this like:

```
foo.prop = 'test'
    Property of foo
```

The same works if `prop` is an attribute of a class. I haven't figured out why it doesn't work in my special case.

Comment: Your code does not work. `ModMeta` isn't defined. Could you please post working code?

Comment: @jterrace Copy-paste fail. Is fixed now ;-)

Comment: Deleted my answer because your original code had `__metaclass_` instead of `__metaclass__`, causing it not to work.

Comment: Are you sure this actually works the way you think it does?  The methods/properties seem to have no access to the module namespace.  For example, if I replace the `pass` statement in `meth()` with `return sys.path` I get this: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'`  Works fine if I just return "Hello" or something like that but not for accessing what should be globals.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior as me?

Comment: @Jacinda Yeah, oddly I'm seeing the same behavior. Never noticed it before. (I've only used builtins for the class.) The `globals()` looks like this (without `__builtins__`): `{'__file__': None, 'ClassAsModule': None, '__package__': None, 'sys': None, 'TestClass': None, '__name__': None, '__doc__': None, 'types': None}`

Comment: I think it's related to the source of the problem, but I haven't quite connected all the dots yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my understanding.

The theory is: making <strike>a mutant</strike> your class act like a module this (a bit hacky) way makes sphinx think that he doesn't need (to parse) properties from modules (because it's a class-level paradigm). So, for sphinx, `TestClass` is a module.

First of all, to make sure that the culprit is the code for making a class act like a module - let's remove it:

```
class ClassAsModule(type):
    pass
```

we'll see in docs:

```
package Package
    script Module

    class package.script.ClassAsModule
        Bases: type

    class package.script.TestClass
        Bases: module

        TestClass docstring.

        meth()
            meth doc

        some_property
            Property docstring.
```

As you see, sphinx read the property without any problems. Nothing special here.

---

Possible solution for your problem is to avoid using `@property` decorator and replace it with calling `property` class constructor. E.g.:

```
import sys
import types

class ClassAsModule(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        # Make sure the name of the class is the module name.
        name = attrs.pop('__module__')
        # Create a class.
        cls = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        # Instantiate the class and register it.
        sys.modules[name] = cls = cls(name)
        # Update the dict so dir works properly
        cls.__dict__.update(attrs)


class TestClass(types.ModuleType):
    """TestClass docstring."""
    __metaclass__ = ClassAsModule

    def get_some_property(self):
        """Property docstring."""
        pass

    some_property = property(get_some_property)

    def meth(self):
        """meth doc"""
        pass
```

For this code sphinx generates:

```
package Package
    script Module
        TestClass docstring.

            package.script.get_some_property(self)
                Property docstring.

            package.script.meth(self)
                meth doc
```

May be the answer is a piece of nonsense, but I hope it'll point you to the right direction.

Comment: Sadly this is missing the point of having the usage of the properties and the documentation in sync.

Comment: Yeah, but, it's important to understand that `@property` decorator is just a syntax sugar. Defining properties via instantiating `property` class as I've suggested works actually the same way as using the decorator. But, sure, in this case, documentation shows somewhat a bit different picture.

Comment: I'm awarding you the bounty because else nobody will receive those points. I won't get a refund and I don't expect an accepted answer soon so it seemed like the 'best' thing to do.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think it would be fair if I start a bounty on this question? Or we should wait a bit?

Comment: I'm fine with either choice. ;-) The last bounty didn't have the desired result, so I'm planning on waiting.

Comment: Ok, let's just wait for a while. Just let me know when and I'll start a bounty - this seems fair. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've found that works best is to keep the file contents the same as if you were writing a regular module, then at the end replace the embryonic module in `sys.modules`:

```
"""Module docstring.  """

import sys
import types

def _some_property(self):
    pass
some_property = property(_some_property)
"""Property docstring."""

def meth():
    """meth doc"""
    pass

def _make_class_module(name):
    mod = sys.modules[name]
    cls = type('ClassModule', (types.ModuleType,), mod.__dict__)
    clsmod = cls(name)
    clsmod.__dict__.update(mod.__dict__)
    clsmod.__wrapped__ = mod
    sys.modules[name] = clsmod
_make_class_module(__name__)
```

Text documentation:

```
mymod Module
************

Module docstring.

mymod.meth()

   meth doc

mymod.some_property = None

   Property docstring.
```

For the version of Sphinx I'm using (v1.1.3), it looks like you have to apply the property constructor explicitly (you can't use it as a decorator), and the docstring has to go in the file at the top level, on the line after the constructor call that creates the property (it doesn't work as a docstring inside the property getter).  The source is still fairly readable, though.