# What is the difference between var, cvar and ivar in python's sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I was reading through the sphinx documentation pages and ironically found that the documentation on the difference between var, ivar, and cvar very lacking.  I was wondering if someone could explain the difference between each of the different name spaces in inline code.

Example:

```
class foo(object):
    """
      :var str first:
      :ivar str last:
      :cvar str middle:
    """
```

How are each of these sphinx tags different from each other and how do I know which one is the correct one to use correctly as designed?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`var` is a generic variable, of course.  Use this when you don't care to make any further distinction about the variable you are documenting.

`ivar` is an "instance variable", or a variable that is set on an instance object (an instance of a class).  Typically these would be defined (in Python) inside of an `__init__` method.

`cvar` is a "class variable", or a variable that is set on a class object directly.  Typically, this would be set inside a class statement, but outside of any particular method in the class.

Here's an example:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    cvar = 'I am a class variable'

    def __init__(self):
        self.ivar = 'I am an instance variable'
```

Answer (score 4):

**Documentation**

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#info-field-lists as of `Sphinx==6.1.3` says they all render exactly the same for now, which is a shame:

> In current release, all var, ivar and cvar are represented as “Variable”. There is no difference at all.

**`:ivar:` vs `:cvar` minimal runnable example**

Here's a minimal runnable example showing how they are likely meant to be used, and how the output looks like. As there is no rendering difference as of `Sphinx==6.1.3` it is just a semantic thing for the source reader for the time being, but worth doing anyways.

Not showing `:var:` because I'm not sure when that is meant to be used! Maybe module level variables would be the best? [How to document a module constant in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227051/how-to-document-a-module-constant-in-python) But it doesn't work there from the module docstring.

main.py

```
class MyOtherClass:
    """
    This class does that.
    """
    pass

class MyClass:
    """
    Description for class.

    :ivar var1: Doc for var1
    :ivar var2: Doc for var2.
      Another line!
    :cvar class_var: Syntax also works for class variables.
    """

    class_var: int

    def __init__(self, par1: int, par2: MyOtherClass):
        self.var1: int = par1

        self.var2: MyOtherClass = par2

    def method(self):
        """
        My favorite method.
        """
        pass

    @classmethod
    def cmethod():
        """
        My favorite class method.
        """
        pass
```

build.sh

```
sphinx-build . out
```

conf.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
extensions = [ 'sphinx.ext.autodoc' ]
autodoc_default_options = {
    'members': True,
}
autodoc_typehints = "description"
```

index.rst

```
.. automodule:: main
```

requirements.txt

```
Sphinx==6.1.3
```

After `./build.sh` the output under `out/index.html` looks like:
[image]

**`#:` doc comments**

This is another way to document instance and class variables.

There are currently tradeoffs between both methods, it is a shame that there isn't one clearly superior method.

Downsides:

- the "Variables:" grouping looks cleaner, TODO link to feature request

Upsides:

- you don't have to type the attribute names multiple times
- types are shown

Both could be better:

- clearly show that `class_var` is a class variable? TODO link to feature request

Besides the `self.var1 = par1 # Doc for var1` syntax you can also:

main.py

```
class MyClass:
    """
    Description for class.
    """

    #: Syntax also works for class variables.
    class_var: int = 1

    def __init__(self, par1: int, par2: MyOtherClass):
        #: Doc for var1
        self.var1: int = par1

        #: Doc for var2.
        #: Another line!
        self.var2: MyOtherClass = par2

    def method(self):
        """
        My favorite method.
        """
        pass

    @classmethod
    def cmethod():
        """
        My favorite class method.
        """
        pass
```

produces:

[image]

The `#:` syntax is documented at: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autoproperty

Tested on Python 3.10, Ubuntu 22.10.

Comment: Your example works only since your variable names are in the desired lexical order. If you rename "class_var" to "the_class_var" it will end up after "method()".

Comment: @Dr.VolkerJaenisch also in the `#:`, non class variables `var1` and `var2` also suffer with the same problem. I do consider this aspect of the the `#:` output inferior (no "Variables" grouping), it is the only downside compared to `:ivar:`, it's a shame.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe don't worry about the distinction between thesr specific tags and simply stick to using 'var' if you need to use it at all, since the documentation indicates that:

There are many other Info fields but they may be redundant:
...(including)...
var, ivar, cvar: Description of a variable.
...

See:

http://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/sphinx/docstring_python.html

Comment: "There are many other Info fields but they may be redundant"
I wish that this was more concrete as to whether or not they were redundant.  I almost don't believe it because it doesn't make sense although it could very well be the case.
Any other leads that we could verify this with?