# How to use @property decorator as a module attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

Following PEP-562:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/

it is now possible to define attribute for a module. Unfortunately some of the built-in component hasn't adapt to this new feature yet. In the following code:

```
@property
def lazyFn():
    return 3

v = lazyFn

v
```

Ideally `v` should have the attribute value 3. Unfortunately, the currently implementation of `@property` only yield the following result:

```
<property at 0x7f3e703eae30>
```

How do I fix it to behave as expected? Or alternatively, where can I find a replacement that has the proper implementation?

Comment: Where do you get the idea this is supposed to work for `@property`? The PEP seems pretty focused on `__getattr__` and `__dir__` exclusively. It's not claiming to add full descriptor support (which is what `property` relies on).

Comment: You are right, the PEP and the decorator are indeed independent but it created a divergence. I'm simply looking for a library that behave consistently on both __getAttr__

Comment: Even if modules were supported, there's no reason to believe it should work without an attribute lookup, and there's no "self" equivalent *in* a module. (One *could* imagine that `import foo; assert foo.lazyFn == 3` would succeed, though.)

Comment: there is a "self" equivalence: python module can be manipulated with reflection. Also, what is the point of `import foo` if lazyFn is defined in the same file?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018676/355230) to another question would be a way to do it.

Comment: @martineau that looks promising but it is too verbose even in C++ standard, I'm looking for a short decorator

Comment: tribbloid: Dunno what C++ standards have to do with anything. Regardless, the linked answer isn't taking advantage of PEP 562, so there may be a way to implement the idea in a more terse fashion.

Answer (score 3):

From Python 3.7 you can implement a custom module `__getattr__`, which could handle this to give `@property`-like behaviour: recalculating every time. (Example based on code in [PEP 562](https://peps.python.org/pep-0562/))

```py
# Inside `some_module.py`
def calc_v():
    return 3
def __getattr__(name):
    if name == 'v':
        return calc_v()
    else:
        raise AttributeError(f'module {__name__} has no attribute {name}')

# Inside another module
import some_module
print(some_module.v) # prints 3
```

Note that `__getattr__` is a fallback method. It will be called when no attribute could be found instead of immediately raising an `AttributeError`, so by implementing a custom `__getattr__` we become responsible for raising the appropriate `AttributeError`.

Then, if calculating `v` is expensive, you can make `calc_v` cache its answer, instead of just re-calculating (i.e. `@functools.cached_property`-like behaviour).

```py
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=1)
def calc_v():
    return 3
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Will verify then accept as canonical answer

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe how easy the answer could be (and how this is not a built-in or bolt-on), there is no need for reflection, module, **setattr**, or PEP-562. All I need is to define a decorator:

```
def lazy(fn):
    if fn.__name__ == fn.__qualname__:
        # not a property
        result = fn()
        return result
    else:
        return LazyProperty(fn)

# the following are from PyPI lazy library
class LazyProperty(object):
    """lazy descriptor
    Used as a decorator to create lazy attributes. Lazy attributes
    are evaluated on first use.
    """

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.__func = func
        functools.wraps(self.__func)(self)

    def __get__(self, inst, inst_cls):
        if inst is None:
            return self

        if not hasattr(inst, '__dict__'):
            raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '__dict__'" % (inst_cls.__name__,))

        name = self.__name__
        if name.startswith('__') and not name.endswith('__'):
            name = '_%s%s' % (inst_cls.__name__, name)

        value = self.__func(inst)
        inst.__dict__[name] = value
        return value
```

to test it:

```
nn = 0


@lazy
def fn1():
    global nn
    nn = nn + 1
    return nn


@dataclass
class HasFn2(object):
    nn = 0

    @lazy
    def fn2(self):
        self.nn = self.nn + 1
        return self.nn


def test_lazy():

    vs1 = [fn1 for i in range(0, 5)]
    assert vs1 == [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

    c = HasFn2()
    vs2 = [c.fn2 for i in range(0, 5)]
    assert (vs2 == [1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

please correct me if this implementation is defective

Comment: This might solve your problem, but it does not solve the problem of having `@property`-like behavior for module attributes as described by the question title. For instance, I would like to evaluate a function every time the module attribute is accessed.

Comment: This implementation is defective :P. For `fn1`, the first branch of the `lazy` decorator is executed, and the function is called immediately, replacing the function with the result of calling that function. That is, fn1 is very much *not* lazy.